# getch expects extra character

Tags: c, macros, getch

Hello I am new to programming and I am writing a program in C.

In my header file I have this macro:

```
#define yesno(c) (c==ENTER || c==' ' || c=='\t') ? ENTER : ESC
```

In my program I have this code

```
char keypressed()
{ char c;
c =getch();
return yesno(getch());
 }
```

So what I wanted to ask is why when I ask to return `yesno(c)` I have to press the button only once, while when I use return `yesno(getch())` I have to press the button one two or three more times?

Is there a problem with `getch()` when called from a macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because when you use

```
yesno(getch());
```

It expands to :

```
(getch()==ENTER || getch()==' ' || getch()=='\t') ? ENTER : ESC`
```

When the macro is expanded like this, it means that `getch()` could actually be called 1, 2 or 3 times because the logical `||` means:

```
getch() == '\n' ? if true return ENTER, false test next one
getch() == ' '  ? if true return ENTER, false test next one
getch() == '\t' ? if true return ENTER, false return ESC
```

If you use the `gcc` compiler you can find out what your macro expands to by using the `-E` flag:

```
gcc -E myprog.c -o mprog.m
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but you please make it more clear? as I said I am new to programming, so I would appreciate it if you could explain me what happens in this case and also where to use gcc. I am sorry if this seems elementary or trivial to you, but I'd like to have a better view.

Comment: @user1827339 I updated the question hope this makes it more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

C uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  The expression you get from your macro:

```
(getch()==ENTER || getch()==' ' || getch()=='\t') ? ENTER : ESC`
```

gets a character, sees if it's equal to ENTER (which you've presumably defined as `\n`.  If it is, the whole expression is going to end up true and so the function returns true without testing the other two cases.  If not, though, the function then gets *another* character, tests whether that second character equals `' '`, and returns true if it does.  Only after testing all three cases on different characters, and getting false each time, is the whole expression known to be false.